# How to calculate using data from previous object and current object in mongodb array of objects using aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following data in mongodb

```
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5641f77344aef29028a86d9b"), 
    "timestamp" : "2015-09-21 00:01:34",  
    "day_chan1" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_chan2" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_chan3" : NumberInt(65), 
    "gatwayId" : "4437191001a3"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5641f77344aef29028a86d9c"), 
    "timestamp" : "2015-09-21 00:02:34",     
    "day_chan1" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_chan2" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_chan3" : NumberInt(97), 
    "gatwayId" : "4437191001a3"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5641f77344aef29028a86d9d"), 
    "timestamp" : "2015-09-21 00:03:34", 
    "day_chan1" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_chan2" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_chan3" : NumberInt(130), 
    "gatwayId" : "4437191001a3"
}
```

and I want to calculate three extra fields ph1,ph2,ph3 from the given data where `ph1 = day_chan1 of current - day_chan2 of previous object`. Can this be done using aggregate in mongoose or pure mongodb ?

Comment: @vmkcom It is not the same as the question you have mentioned.

Comment: But there are answer for your question - if you want to use existing value, you needs to iterate throught objects and calculate what you want. It cannot be done as single query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Aggregate for a sum on a per week basis for all prior weeks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577908/mongodb-aggregate-for-a-sum-on-a-per-week-basis-for-all-prior-weeks). "Running totals" require a "global" which the aggregation framework does not have. Only mapReduce can do that on the server, or live with calculation in the client on response instead.

Comment: That would be using javascript to take care of your problem which in turn will slow down the whole application. I have 1300000 objects to work with and I need something really fast and as far as i know aggregate is the faster way to do it

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks, its similar to what i need

Comment: Actually the answer given shows examples of "exactly what you need", with two approaches. That is what the duplicate banner you are seeing is prompting you to do. Confirm that the linked response answers your question. There are no other ways to solve this than the two approaches given.